# Having Problems Getting The Correct Widget Area To Display

Tags: php, css, wordpress, widget

I have probably missed something but I have been trying to work out what and I am having no luck.
I have added a new page template to my wordpress site, created a new widget area (necessary as this is how the original designer built the site). 
However, the page appears to be calling content from another widget area.
The page in question is http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/builders-painters-decorators-and-refurbishment-contractors-surrey/ and it appears to be calling widget area "New Paint" despite the code calling for "paint surrey" which contains the correct text for the widget area.
For note the widget area is basically the bottom half of the page.

I hope someone might be able to help me get my head round this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
As you have created a separate sidebar, now you must be seeing that in your admin panel.

So just add the widgets you want to appear in the sidebar.

Next go to your sidebar.php page, there you cana put a condition i.e. for the products page

If your products page is a separate template then use the name of the file i.e.

if ( is_page_template('your-template.php') ) {
    register_sidebr('name of the sidebar');
} else {
    register_sidebr('name of the sidebar');
}
```